# How Do I Adjust the Depth of an Octagonal Junction Box?

Tags: light-fixture, junction-box

The junction box for a wall mounted light will be 1/4 in. shy of the finished drywall. The house is 50 yrs old. How do I adjust the depth of the octagonal junction box? Is there a safe way to shim or extend it? I've seen some octagonal box extenders online, but they didn't appear to be adjustable.

[image: Holding A Scrap of Drywall to Show Depth]

[image: The Junction Box is Mounted on a U-shaped Bar]

Comment: Is having the box stick out from the wall acceptable?

Comment: That box looks like it has an adjustable center mount. Loosen the inside and tighten the nut on the outside where it attaches to the hanger bar.

Answer (score 2):

Per Tyson's comment;  You should be able to move the box on the threaded nipple (pipe) that seems to be holding it to the hanger bar.

Loosen the nut, in the box,  down to the desired height.  Then tighten the one outside the box above it.  Since you had the ceiling open (at least when this was OP) that shouldn't be to hard.  Worse case you may have to back the wires out, remove the box from the nipple, and stack a nut up at the desired height and reassemble.

Answer (score 0):

Your options are several here.

1. Remove the hanger bar and reshape the bends at its ends so that it brings the center portion of the bar out by the sufficient amount.
2. Replace the hanger bar with another technique for securing the box. That could be a wood header mounted behind the box between the two studs on either side.
3. Subject to wiring lengths and ability to re-route plan for a new electrical box that is mounted directly to the adjacent stud.